# I use openssl API to replace the command, but the decrypted data header is error. why?

Tags: api, openssl, command

I use openssl API to replace the command line below. But the decryped file head is error.Could somebody help me?

```
#openssl  enc -d  -aes192 -pass "pass:3eDc#9ujN"  -p -in  hfb1062.enc -out a.cpio
salt=28C7761EE45FFB06
key=00297EE7F640FB3545C9466583B9D008A4EB3CF24A4EFF65
iv =F4F137201648930D6BA620806691EF71
```

The salf, key and iv is the same as the openssl command line output.
Here is code to implement the about openssl command line:

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>


unsigned char key[EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH], iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];
const EVP_CIPHER *cipher=NULL;
int pass2keyiv(char *infile)
{
    const char magic[]="Salted__";
    char mbuf[sizeof magic-1];

    const EVP_MD *dgst = NULL;
    unsigned char salt[PKCS5_SALT_LEN];
    const char *password = "3eDc#9ujN";
    int i;

    BIO *in=NULL;
    in=BIO_new(BIO_s_file());

    printf("Please specify openssl enc -in arg [file]\n");
    {
    //argv[1] openssl enc -in 
        if (BIO_read_filename(in,infile) <= 0)
        {
            perror(infile);
            return;
        }
        printf("her BIO_read_filename argv[1]=%s \n",infile);
    }
     printf("her in %p \n",in);

     if((BIO_read(in,mbuf,sizeof mbuf) != sizeof mbuf
                      || BIO_read(in,
                              (unsigned char *)salt,
                    sizeof salt) != sizeof salt)){
      perror("read salt error");
      return;
    }
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    cipher = EVP_get_cipherbyname("aes192");//"aes-192-cbc");
    if(!cipher) { fprintf(stderr, "no such cipher\n"); return 1; }

    dgst=EVP_get_digestbyname("md5");
    if(!dgst) { fprintf(stderr, "no such digest\n"); return 1; }

    if(!EVP_BytesToKey(cipher, dgst, salt,
        (unsigned char *) password,
        strlen(password), 1, key, iv))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "EVP_BytesToKey failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("salt: "); for(i=0; i<PKCS5_SALT_LEN; ++i) { printf("%02x", salt[i]); } printf("\n");
    printf("Key: "); for(i=0; i<cipher->key_len; ++i) { printf("%02x", key[i]); } printf("\n");
    printf("IV: "); for(i=0; i<cipher->iv_len; ++i) { printf("%02x", iv[i]); } printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

int do_crypt(FILE *in, FILE *out)
{
    #define BSIZE   (8*1024)
    char inbuf[BSIZE]={0}, outbuf[BSIZE + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH]={0};
    const char magic[]="Salted__";
    char mbuf[sizeof magic-1];

    int inlen, outlen;

    char * needle =NULL;


    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);

    if(fread(mbuf,1,sizeof mbuf,in) != sizeof mbuf)//If I skip the magic size or remove this code line, the decryped data is also wrong.
        printf("bad magic number\n");
    printf("Magic number %s\n",mbuf); 

    //do_encrypt:1 for encryption,0 for decryption
    EVP_CipherInit_ex(&ctx,cipher, NULL, key, iv, 0);

    for(;;)
    {
        bzero(inbuf,sizeof inbuf);
        inlen = fread(inbuf, 1, BSIZE, in);
        if(inlen <= 0) break;
        bzero(outbuf,sizeof outbuf);
        if(!EVP_CipherUpdate(&ctx, outbuf, &outlen, inbuf, inlen))
        {
            /* Error */
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
            return 0;
        }


        fwrite(outbuf, 1, outlen, out);
    }
    if(!EVP_CipherFinal_ex(&ctx, outbuf, &outlen))
    {
        /* Error */
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
        return 0;
    }
    fwrite(outbuf, 1, outlen, out);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc,char**argv)
{
    FILE *in=fopen(argv[1],"rb");
    FILE *out=fopen(argv[2],"wb");
    if ( argc != 3){
        printf("Usage: in_file_to_be_decryped out_file%d\n",argc);
        return;
    }
    if (NULL ==in){
        printf("error fopen\n");
        return 0;
    }
    pass2keyiv(argv[1]);
    do_crypt(in,out);
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OpenSSL envelops the data, while you aren't doing this, i.e. calling the functions directly doesn't do the envelope for you. If you look at what OpenSSL generates, you will notice it has a header of `__Slated`

Comment: If I try to skip the "Salted__"  size from the input file, but it also is wrong.

Comment: You cannot SKIP it, it is an important part, you need to process it, after the `__Slated`, file header, comes I think, 16bytes of the salt, followed by the encrypted data. From the salt you will gain access to the IV, which will then be used to decrypt the data

Comment: Could you describe it more detail? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, for me I had to solve it in a perl script, you can make it into Java, pretty easily.

**NOTE** I am using DES so the salt size and location is different than yours. I also use `DES_EDE`, you will need to use `AES`

```
my $salt = substr($data, 8, 8);
my $ct = substr($data, 16);

my $rounds = 3;
my $data00 = $Key.$salt;
my @md5_hash;
$md5_hash[0] = md5($data00);
my $result = $md5_hash[0];
for (my $i = 1; $i < $rounds; $i++) {
 $md5_hash[$i] = md5($md5_hash[$i - 1].$data00);
 $result .= $md5_hash[$i];
}

my $key = substr($result, 0, 24);
my $iv  = substr($result, 24, 8);

my $m = Crypt::Mode::CFB->new('DES_EDE');
my $plaintext = $m->decrypt($ct, $key, $iv);

return $plaintext;
```

For your `AES`, I believe the salt length will be `16`, so the `ct` (ciphertext) will start at position `24`. I also think AES uses `SHA` and not `MD5`, but I am not 100% sure of that.

Comment: I have skip the magic size when decrypting the input data, but also error.

Comment: I suspect you use "my $ct = substr($data, 16);" to skip the salt size.

Comment: I tried your way and It's successful. Thanks.The block size is 16. so skip the block size, instead of the Salted__

Comment: Great to hear it worked, post an answer with your solution, so others will be able to use it

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution: I think we should skip a block size, which is a default padding when encrypting.

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>

/*
#openssl  enc -d  -aes192 -pass "pass:3eDc#9ujN"  -p -in  hfb1062.enc -out a.cpio
salt=28C7761EE45FFB06
key=00297EE7F640FB3545C9466583B9D008A4EB3CF24A4EFF65
iv =F4F137201648930D6BA620806691EF71
*/

unsigned char key[EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH], iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];
const EVP_CIPHER *cipher=NULL;
int pass2keyiv(char *infile)
{
    const char magic[]="Salted__";
    char mbuf[sizeof magic-1];

    const EVP_MD *dgst = NULL;
    unsigned char salt[PKCS5_SALT_LEN];
    const char *password = "3eDc#9ujN";
    int i;

    BIO *in=NULL;
    in=BIO_new(BIO_s_file());

    printf("Please specify openssl enc -in arg [file]\n");
    {
    //argv[1] openssl enc -in 
        if (BIO_read_filename(in,infile) <= 0)
        {
            perror(infile);
            return;
        }
        printf("her BIO_read_filename argv[1]=%s \n",infile);
    }
     printf("her in %p \n",in);

     if((BIO_read(in,mbuf,sizeof mbuf) != sizeof mbuf
                      || BIO_read(in,
                              (unsigned char *)salt,
                    sizeof salt) != sizeof salt)){
      perror("read salt error");
      return;
    }
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    cipher = EVP_get_cipherbyname("aes192");//"aes-192-cbc");
    if(!cipher) { fprintf(stderr, "no such cipher\n"); return 1; }

    dgst=EVP_get_digestbyname("md5");
    if(!dgst) { fprintf(stderr, "no such digest\n"); return 1; }

    if(!EVP_BytesToKey(cipher, dgst, salt,
        (unsigned char *) password,
        strlen(password), 1, key, iv))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "EVP_BytesToKey failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("salt: "); for(i=0; i<PKCS5_SALT_LEN; ++i) { printf("%02x", salt[i]); } printf("\n");
    printf("Key: "); for(i=0; i<cipher->key_len; ++i) { printf("%02x", key[i]); } printf("\n");
    printf("IV: "); for(i=0; i<cipher->iv_len; ++i) { printf("%02x", iv[i]); } printf("\n");

    if (in != NULL) BIO_free(in);

    return 0;
}

int do_crypt(FILE *in, FILE *out)
{
    #define BSIZE   (8*1024)
    char inbuf[BSIZE]={0}, outbuf[BSIZE + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH]={0};

    int inlen, outlen;
    char * needle =NULL;
    char mblock[1024];
    int blocksize=0;

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);

    blocksize = EVP_CIPHER_block_size(cipher);
    printf("block size %d\n",blocksize);

    fread(mblock,1,blocksize,in);//skip the magic size

    //EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(&ctx, 1);
    //do_encrypt:1 for encryption,0 for decryption
    EVP_CipherInit_ex(&ctx,cipher, NULL, key, iv, 0);


    for(;;)
    {
        bzero(inbuf,sizeof inbuf);
        inlen = fread(inbuf, 1, BSIZE, in);
        if(inlen <= 0) break;
        bzero(outbuf,sizeof outbuf);
        if(!EVP_CipherUpdate(&ctx, outbuf, &outlen, inbuf, inlen))
        {
            /* Error */
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
            return 0;
        }

        fwrite(outbuf, 1, outlen, out);
    }
    if(!EVP_CipherFinal_ex(&ctx, outbuf, &outlen))
    {
        /* Error */
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
        return 0;
    }
    fwrite(outbuf, 1, outlen, out);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc,char**argv)
{
    FILE *in=fopen(argv[1],"rb");
    FILE *out=fopen(argv[2],"wb");
    if ( argc != 3){
        printf("Usage: in_file_to_be_decryped out_file%d\n",argc);
        return;
    }
    if (NULL ==in){
        printf("error fopen\n");
        return 0;
    }
    pass2keyiv(argv[1]);
    do_crypt(in,out);
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```